# How disable django admin pagination?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-pagination

I need turn off django admin pagination. I use mttp in django and I need disable pagination on some admin module.

How I can do it?
Or how I can make pagination only by parents?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

If you're using Django 1.8 (the newest version), there is a new setting on the ModelAdmin class called `show_full_result_count` that I believe will do what you're looking for. You can set it to false and it will disable the pagination on the Django admin view.

Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.show_full_result_count

Comment: No, I'm using Django 1.7

Comment: There are some hacky solutions for non-1.8 -- you can see the discussion on the issue here: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/4065

Comment: This wont disable pagination. It will just remove the indication of the total number of entries in the table, which requires an extra query and can slow down the whole page.

Comment: `show_full_result_count` does not disable pagination as Weier mentioned

Answer (score 2):

The number of items per page is determined by [`ModelAdmin.list_per_page`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_per_page).

As [@codingjoe's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29739244/how-disable-django-admin-pagination#comment68386558_38312366) suggests, setting this to [`sys.maxsize`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/sys.html#sys.maxsize) is very likely to suffice.

```
import sys

class PartAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_per_page = sys.maxsize
```

Answer (score -3):

I do this in order to put everything on one page:

```
class PartAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_per_page = Part.objects.all().count()
    list_max_show_all = list_per_page
```

It just counts all the parts (my model is called "Part") and then makes that the max number per page.

Comment: That will case a query during app loading. You could also just use `sys.maxsize`